# cts:value-co-occurrences() vs cts:value-tuples() Index latency

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have one Marklogic DB in place where I have implemented root level fragmentation, added element and path range indexes.

Now, I am writing a query to generate a kind of report with the help of created Indexes. For this I am using cts:value-co-occurrences() and cts:value-tuples() function of Marklogic.

My query is giving me correct output for small data. But, whenever I am doing bulk upload into the system which has all the configuration in place, my cts:value-co-occurrences() is not giving the result. I am getting empty result. I have done re-indexing and after re-indexing I run the code again, but still no result is coming.

The function where I am using cts:value-co-occurrences() is specifically looking for fragmented documents.

So, my question is, if we have fragmentation in place, how we can track the indexing time of the system as Marklogic DB is not showing any indication for fragment level indexing information. How can we rid off this?

Comment: Can you tell more about your data structure, and how/why you are using fragmentation? It is usually sub-optimal..

Comment: Also, did you consider using Template Driven Extraction to generate SQL-like views? That usually has a much smaller memory footprint, and can yield more accurate results even without using fragmentation.

Comment: I have root element <article> which has  one child <products> with <product> child element. I am using fragmentation for product because I want to generate some report on the basis of product's elements. Whenever I run co-occurance query, it is clubbing it's child into one map. For example every product has unique product ID and and some another children like price. So, whenever I run co-occurance query it returns all unique price value without considering product code. After fragmentation it is working fine. I have't think about the SQL like views. But I think it will return same result.

Comment: TDE allows you to pick a context node, and be more specific about what should be part of the same row, and what not. Give it a try: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE

Comment: Yes, this is another approach to perform the same task. But, still there Is something missing in Marklogic which is blocking to create path rang index while using fragmentation. I checked it for one XML file only, but surprisingly ML is unable to produce any error and result.